# How to apply CSS to dropdown items

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to add a round symbol for every item in a dropdown . The color of the round symbol depends on a condition; if active ===1 the symbol should display in green otherwise in red.

```
   Group: <select value={this.state.group} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ group: e.target.value, provider: })}>
   <option value=''>Select</option>
{this.state.groups.map((item) => <option value={item.GRPID}><span><span style={item.active === 1?{color:'green'}:{color:'red'}}>●</span>{item.GRPName}</span></option>)}
                            </select>
```

Here is my code, the symbol is displaying but the CSS I applied is not working and also the symbol is displayed when we select an item from the dropdown, I don't need it too.

Comment: You want color to be green when active===0 but in code snippet you are doing it when active===1

Comment: Question edited, please check

Comment: Does the answer work for you?

Comment: @kooskoos I tried, but it is not working

Comment: Check out a simple example I created.

Comment: Yeah I checked it, I don't know why this code doesn't work in my code

Comment: Can you log item.active inside map and see what it's value is?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a codesandbox to display a simple example https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-snyder-m9egg

Check it out.